# Tips for Setting Up Complex CTAGS Search Paths

Tags: linux, vim, ctags

I want to be able to start up vim in an arbitrary subdirectory in my project and have it search up to the project root for the `tags` file, and then to search in an unrelated directory outside the project tree.

For example let's say I have the following:

```
~/projects/foo/bar/baz.c
~/projects/foo/tags
~/some/arbitrary/path/tags
```

I want to open `baz.c` from within the `bar` subdirectory, have it search up to find `foo/tags` and then to search `some/arbitrary/path/tags` if the symbol isn't found in `foo/tags`.

Now I know I can do:

```
set tags=./tags,tags;
```

to accomplish the first task.  It's apparently the semicolon which tells vim to search up to the root.  However neither of the following work:

```
set tags=./tags,tags,~/some/arbitrary/path/tags;
set tags=./tags,tags;~/some/arbitrary/path/tags
```

The first one finds only symbols from `~/some/arbitrary/path/tags` while the second one only finds symbols in the tags file at the project root.

Anyone know how to do this?  I'm on Linux buy the way.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the simicolon is right.  Are you sure you're in the current directory you think you're in?  Try :pwd from within vim.  I've been using multiple tags separated with a comma for years with both relative and absolute paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use:

```
set tags=~/.tags
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/cpp
set tags+=~/src/git/gitsrc/tags
" and so on...
```

For generating tags in a particular project's root:

```
map <C-F12> :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<CR>
```

I adapted this setup from the [C++ code completion vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion).

Comment: Splitting the set command up into multiple lines solved the problem for me.  I ended up with `set tags=tags;` in my `.vimrc` and then typing `:set tags+=~/some/arbitrary/path/tags` from within vim.

Answer (score 0):

replace the tilde with path to your home.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.  I tried both `set tags=./tags,tags,/home/myuser/some/arbitrary/path/tags;` and 
`set tags=./tags,tags;/home/myuser/some/arbitrary/path/tags`

Comment: how are you testing it? What exactly is happening? I created a tags file in a programming directory of mine, edited my .vimrc to include that path in "set tags", using the tilde as the starting point. Then, I made a dummy file, test.c, in my home directory (so, not in the directory with the tags file), wrote the name of a function that would be listed in the tags file, and pressed "ctrl-]" with the cursor over the function. Took me right where it was supposed to.

Comment: I set the search path manually inside vim.  I test by looking for two symbols, one symbol from a separate file in the same project whose tags file is a few directories up in the project root, and then looking for a symbol from the external tags file on the arbitrary path.  Depending on which version of the path I use I find one symbol, or the other, but never both.

Answer (score 0):

Your first "set tags" option works for me in Linux. (As in, I've done it before, and I just recreated it to be sure.) You can have many different paths in your tags option, both absolute and relative. However, in the second one, you have a semicolon in the middle of the list, which is incorrect. In fact, you don't need any semi-colon. I would also replace the ~ with the absolute path to your home, just in case, and remove the semicolons all together. Just have commas between each path.

Oh, and to search up a directory for the tags file, you need "../tags", not "./tags". A single dot means the current directory, two dots means the directory one up from where you are.

Comment: Could you post exactly how you recreated it since I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Are you opening the file from the project root or from the subdirectory?  I'm opening the file from within a subdirectory in the project, not the project root.

Comment: This is what I have:
 set tags=./TAGS,./tags,tags,TAGS,~/programming/mandelbrot/main/tags
where the last directory is the absolute path. As I mentioned above, it won't search in any parent directories, since I'm not using ../tags.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to search up to the project root from the current directory.  That's what the semicolon in `tags=./tags,tags;` allows.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to get it to both do that and **then** search the second external path if the symbol wasn't found.  I need to search up to the project root because I might be in some directory of arbitrary depth in the project.  My OP was a very simplified but representative example.

Answer (score 0):

Is the tags file always in the project/ directory?  If so, you don't need to "search up" to find the tags file.  Just hard code the path to both files like this:

```
set tags=/home/you/projects/foo/tags;/home/you/some/arbitrary/path/tags
```

If not, you can try something like this:

```
set tags=/home/you/projects/**;/home/you/projects,/home/you/some/arbitrary/path/tags
```

I haven't tried this so you might have to experiment with it.  There are some pre-conditions for it to work.  See :help file-searching.

Answer (score 0):

The single line syntax for set tags should be:

```
set tags=./tags,tags;,~/some/arbitrary/path/tags
```

The comma was missing after "tags;"